# Connecting block chain front end with smart contracts

Tags: solidity, blockchain

[https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/3097/edit#*=*](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/3097/edit#_=_)

after this link how to call functions.
suppose my contract name is bank and i have deposit fucntion in it. when i am using bank.deposit(1000) it is showing error that bank is undefined.
how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to use the web3.js library to interact with your contract. If your bank contract has been deployed, then you will have to create a contract instance in web3 to interact with it. Using that instance you can access its functions and call them. So it goes something like this:

```
var web3 = require("web3");
var fs = require("fs");
var solc = require("solc");

web3 = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var compiledCode = solc.compile(fs.readFileSync('./bank.sol', 'utf8'),1);
var source = compiledCode.contracts[":array"];
var tokencontract = new  web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(source.interface));
tokencontract.deploy({data: source.bytecode}).send({from: UserAddress , gas:1500000}).on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ console.log(confirmationNumber); tokencontract.options.address = receipt.contractAddress; }).on('receipt', function(receipt){console.log(receipt)})
tokencontract.methods.deposit(100).call().then(console.log)
```